# Primary key defined by many attributes?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

Can I define a primary key according to three attributes? I am using Visual Paradigm and Postgres.

```
CREATE TABLE answers (
  time                          SERIAL NOT NULL, 
  "{Users}{userID}user_id"     int4 NOT NULL, 
  "{Users}{userID}question_id" int4 NOT NULL, 
  reply                        varchar(255), 
  PRIMARY KEY (time, "{Users}{userID}user_id", "{Users}{userID}question_id"));
```

A [picture](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175588/SO/primary_key.png) may clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, just as you showed.(though I question your naming of the 2. and 3. column.)

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/ddl-constraints.html):

"Primary keys can also constrain more than one column; the syntax is similar to unique constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    a integer,
    b integer,
    c integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (a, c)
);
```

A primary key indicates that a column or group of columns can be used as a unique identifier for rows in the table. (This is a direct consequence of the definition of a primary key. Note that a unique constraint does not, by itself, provide a unique identifier because it does not exclude null values.) This is useful both for documentation purposes and for client applications. For example, a GUI application that allows modifying row values probably needs to know the primary key of a table to be able to identify rows uniquely.

A table can have at most one primary key (while it can have many unique and not-null constraints). Relational database theory dictates that every table must have a primary key. This rule is not enforced by PostgreSQL, but it is usually best to follow it.
"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There is just such an example in the [documentation.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2336). However, I'm not familiar with the bracketed terms you're using. Are you doing some variable evaluation before creating the database schema?

Comment: It is because of the software, VP.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes you can
2. if you'd run it - you would see it in no time.
3. i would really, really, really suggest to rethink naming convention. time column that contains serial integer? column names like "{Users}{userID}user_id"? oh my.